# Prevent calling DataColumn.ColumnChanged Event when updated by same value

Tags: c#

Is there a property for Data Column to prevent calling Column Changed event, when the Data Column of a DataTable has been edit by the same value ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. The event is raised regardless of the value.

But you can check the value before you update the column to prevent an event from being raised when not needed, e.g.:

```
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
object newValue = "new...";
if (dt.Rows[row][column] != newValue)
    dt.Rows[row][column] = newValue;
```